# CentOS/Xen Hypervisor Completely Locked-Up, Where To Look For Answers

Tags: centos, xen

Our hypervisor server running `CentOS` and `Xen` completely locked-up just right now. The screen was completely blank. I had to hard reboot, and everything came back up normally. No indication of a hardware failure from Dell diagnostics.

I have gone through `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/dmesg` is there anywhere else to look for logging for what may have happened?